# How to properly use large screen monitors

Tags: images

I have a 48" tv hooked up to a computer and I am trying to use it as best I can.  I am making a web app that displays daily quotes in a grid format and it takes up the whole page. for example a grid of 9x4 = 36 small pictures, my pictures have some text on them which becomes unreadable on small laptops but when I output to a tv it is still unreadable yet the pictures are bigger because its on a 48" tv.

Please check out http://jsfiddle.net/hX46r/1/

How can I make the pictures with text on them readable when viewing on large screen TVs.

Also the web app is going to be made for windows 8, can windows 8 properly use the screen size to show pictures clearly?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. If the text is unreadable when output on the larger screen then it's still too small. (?) I don't see how "Windows 8" will improve this. However, in your example, you could use a much clearer font that would read better at those sizes. The font you have used (serif bold condensed) is more suited to headings. A better "body" font might even resolve this. A 48" TV probably has the same resolution as a 24" monitor. eg. 1920 x 1080 would be common in the UK. And some tablets (ie. small screens) have larger resolutions that this, so size doesn't always matter.

Answer (score 1):

Generally common TV's nowadays will work at 720p (1280px x 720px) or 1080p (1920px x 1080px) the readability will rely on several factors:

1. The resolution and quality of the image being served.. a image that is 1920 x 1080px will become more readable than a image up-scaled from 480p or 720p.
2. The Hz of the TV can also be a factor.. Generally still images and motion video will be more sharp on a screen with higher Hertz than one with lower hertz.
3. Generally text outputted via an APP supported by the TV will be more readable than a image containing text within the image.. This is because the TV has its own fonts and anti-alias smoothing and sharpening to the fonts.

The image in your FIDDLE is far too small and should be no less than 1920x1080 or 1280x720